# How to create notification

Tags: java, android, push-notification, android-notifications

I want to create a simple notification in my app, but I can't. I searched for that, I read questions here and the google doc, but I don't know why it is not working. I watched that code from a video, but it doesnt work too.

```
private final String CHANNEL_ID = "personal_notifications";
private final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 001;

public void displayNotification(View view) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,CHANNEL_ID);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.power);
        builder.setContentTitle("Noti");
        builder.setContentText("mukodj mar");
        builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please post what you have tried so far.  Also have you had a look at [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification) yet?

Comment: Edited the post. And yeah I read it.

Comment: Did you created the channel before showing notification? And are you calling `notificationManager.notify()`?

Comment: Yeah, made it. Its working.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code in a BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent repeating_intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    repeating_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 100, repeating_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle contentStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
        contentStyle.bigText((CharSequence) sb.toString()); 
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context) // channel ID missing
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                    .setStyle(contentStyle)
                    .setContentTitle("Title")
                    .setContentText(sb.toString())
                    .setAutoCancel(true);
            notificationManager.notify(100, builder.build());
}
```

I think you forgot the last line:

```
notificationManager.notify(100, builder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I made notification channel and its working now, anyway thanks guys!